# ArrayList item undesirably repeated in DialogFragment

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, android-adapter, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to show different content for different tabs in my `DialogFragment`, but for some reason the content text keeps repating the first item regardless of the tab selected. The tab names are appearing corretly as expected though.  I believe the issue lies in the `DialogFragment` class, within the `for` loop around `createInstance`, but I don't know what needs to change in that area.

**Expected result**

- **Tab A** with **Description A**
- **Tab B** with **Description B**
- **Tab C** with **Description C**

**Current result**

- All tabs show **Description A**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Item class**

```
data class Item (val myDialogTitle: String,
                 val myDialogDescription: String)
```

**Adapter class**

```
class MyDialogAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
    private var mTitleCollection: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    private var mFragmentCollection: MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()

    fun addFragment(title: String, fragment: Fragment) {
        mTitleCollection.add(title)
        mFragmentCollection.add(fragment)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return mTitleCollection[position]
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentCollection[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentCollection.size
    }
}
```

**DialogFragment class**

```
class MyDialog(val myList: ArrayList<Item>) : DialogFragment() {    
    private var mText = ""

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return customView
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val b = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setTitle("Dialog Title")
                .setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok)) { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }

        val adapter = MyDialogAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        for (item in myListTitles) {
            adapter.addFragment(id, MyDialog.createInstance(myListDescriptions[id]))
        }

        b.setView(customView)
        return b.create()
    }

    companion object {
        fun createInstance(txt: String): MyDialog {
            val fragment = MyDialog()
            fragment.mText = txt
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment class**

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val v = view

        mRecyclerView = v!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.my_recyclerview)

        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        val myList = ArrayList<Item>()

        val myListTitles = ArrayList<String>()
        myListTitles.add("Tab A")
        myListTitles.add("Tab B")
        myListTitles.add("Tab C")

        val myListDescriptions = ArrayList<String>()
        myListDescriptions.add("Description A")
        myListDescriptions.add("Description B")
        myListDescriptions.add("Description C")


        val mAdapter = MyAdapter(myList, childFragmentManager)

        mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Please share the MyDialog.createInstance() body
2. Where is MyFragment being used?

Comment: @RishabhJain What do you mean by the `MyDialog.createInstance() body`?

Comment: where did you define the createInstance() method in MyDialog

Comment: In `onCreateDialog`

Comment: Where am I supposed to define it if you believe that's wrong?

Comment: Can you post the body of the createInstance() method?

Comment: Sure. Just added that, I forgot to include that before.

Comment: I'm not able to understand the hierarchy of your app. You have a DialogFragment that has 3 tabs. In each tab, you want to show the same DialogFragment?

Comment: No, I don't. Read the **Expected result** section, that's what I want.

Comment: But which fragment do you want to show in the tab?

Comment: **Tab A** with **Description A**; **Tab B** with **Description B**; **Tab C** with **Description C**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192571/discussion-between-rishabh-jain-and-macaronlover).

Comment: Why leave the chat? The problem hasn't been solved.